# Salesforce1 Mobile SSO with OpenID Connect, possible?

Tags: salesforce1-app, single-sign-on, mobile, saml, open-id-connect

Reading through the SSO possibilities, I found nothing related to SalesforceApp SSO with the OpenID Connect

I got documentation related only to implementation with SAML

Is is possible by any chance to make Salesforce1 to use SSO with OpenID Connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use SSO with OpenID connect. Follow these steps to configure OpenID connect external auth provider:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/sso_provider_openid_connect.htm

> To configure it on Salesforce App *(aka Salesforce1)*, you will need to restrict the org to login exclusively through SSO *(this is done on 'My Domain Configurations')* and then set up a connection on SF1 with your custom domain. With these steps done, the login page of SF1 will be the login page of your configured IDP

Comment: This article is about to use a third-party app as Auth Provider. The question is related to use SSO with OpenID Connect on Salesforce App (previous Salesforce1)

Comment: Maybe I'm following the use case here. Auth Provider is needed to implement OpenId Connect in Salesforce. You can implement your own auth provider with Open Id Connect as provider type or use Salesforce or a third-party as provider type. You will use the Single Sign-On Initialization URL on mobile app to redirect the user to auth provider for auth. What is your use case here? What is the IdP here?

Comment: It's to use SSO on mobile, on the Salesforce app (aka Salesforce1). Salesforce is the service provider and the IdP is a keycloak service (below keycloak it uses LDAP and active directory)